# Xml Parsing and Comparison

Tags: java, xmlunit

I have two Xml:-

```
String xmlA="<user><name>Jai</name><age>31</age><dob>28March1990</dob></user>";
String xmlB="<user><name>Jai Singh</name><age>31</age><dob>28March1990</dob></user>";
```

Now After parsing and comparing, I want to show the results in following
order:-

Name : **Jai    JaiSingh**

Age:    31    31

dob:   28March1990  28March1990

My question:
What is the easiest method to approach this?

Can I use xmlUnit for comparing in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using xmlunit

Create two xml documents and compare using `Diff`.  The `DifferenceEngine` accepts a `DifferenceListener`.  You can add your logic there.

```
        Diff diff = new Diff(docx1, docx2);
        DifferenceEngine engine = new DifferenceEngine(diff);

        ElementQualifier qualifier = new RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier();
        diff = new Diff(docx1, docx2, engine, qualifier);
        diff.overrideDifferenceListener(new DifferenceListener()
        {
            @Override public int differenceFound(Difference difference)
            {
                // Do some thing here


            }

            @Override public void skippedComparison(Node node, Node node1)
            {
                //no op
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you have a XML Unit if you want to compare two XML and you could do it character by character.
[XML Unit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/)

Edited:

You have to download de XMLUnit JAR from here [XML Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlunit/files/xmlunit%20for%20Java/XMLUnit%20for%20Java%201.4/xmlunit-1.4-bin.zip/download) and then its easy, like JUnit, add to your classpath (by Eclipse / NetBeans / so on ...) and then you write a Test, like JUnit but extends from XMLTestCase, like this one:

```
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.*;
public class XMLTesting extends XMLTestCase {


 public void testForEquality() throws Exception {
        String myControlXML = "<msg><uuid>0x00435A8C</uuid></msg>";
        String myTestXML = "<msg><localId>2376</localId></msg>";
        assertXMLEqual("comparing test xml to control xml", myControlXML, myTestXML);

        assertXMLNotEqual("test xml not similar to control xml", myControlXML, myTestXML);
    }

    public void testIdentical() throws Exception {
        String myControlXML = "<struct><int>3</int><boolean>false</boolean></struct>";
        String myTestXML = "<struct><boolean>false</boolean><int>3</int></struct>";
        Diff myDiff = new Diff(myControlXML, myTestXML);
        assertTrue("pieces of XML are similar " + myDiff, myDiff.similar());
        assertTrue("but are they identical? " + myDiff, myDiff.identical());
    }

    public void testAllDifferences() throws Exception {
        String myControlXML = "<news><item id=\"1\">War</item>"
            + "<item id=\"2\">Plague</item><item id=\"3\">Famine</item></news>";
        String myTestXML = "<news><item id=\"1\">Peace</item>"
            + "<item id=\"2\">Health</item><item id=\"3\">Plenty</item></news>";
        DetailedDiff myDiff = new DetailedDiff(compareXML(myControlXML, myTestXML));
        List allDifferences = myDiff.getAllDifferences();
        assertEquals(myDiff.toString(), 0, allDifferences.size());
    }
```

So you can see the easy way to compare two XML

Comment: can you please clarify any further?